# The act of breaking functions apart is called what?

Tags: function, paradigms

Typically I implement classes (C#, C++) via many private functions that serve no purpose other than to separate concerns & logic for readability, maintainability, and scope. For example, if I see a function that is 100 lines long and has 3 comments in it separating it out into virtual 1/3 section chunks, that to me is 3 functions. So I break that larger function out into 3 smaller ones and now that original function only calls 3 functions.

I don't know the name for this paradigm. At first I thought it might be functional programming or modular programming, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Can anyone help me figure out what this paradigm is called? Additionally, a link to a wikipedia article I could read that talks about this exact use case would be great (Of course if you tell me the name of the paradigm I could easily look this up myself).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is one of the most common things I have to do to "legacy" code.  Unfortunately, I can't find this as a built in refactoring option in Netbeans (7), and I don't remember it being in Eclipse, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refactoring is changing the code w/o changing its behavior.  When you break code into more methods, it's called Refactoring to Method.  When you take those methods and put their behaviors into many *classes* (which can help maintain single responsibilities per object/class), it's called Refactoring to *Objects*.

Answer (score 1):

It's basically just "Refactoring".

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring

Answer (score 1):

The actual refactoring practice of creating a new, smaller method from existing code in a oversized method is called [Extract Method](http://refactoring.com/catalog/extractMethod.html).

### Example

**Original code**

```
void printOwing() {
    printBanner();

    //print details
    System.out.println ("name:  " + _name);
    System.out.println ("amount " + getOutstanding());
}
```

**After performing Extract Method**

```
void printOwing() {
    printBanner();
    printDetails(getOutstanding());
}

void printDetails (double outstanding) {
    System.out.println ("name:  " + _name);
    System.out.println ("amount " + outstanding);
}
```

If the code you are trying to pull out of a method doesn't even belong in the class to begin with, then you can similarly use [Extract Class](http://refactoring.com/catalog/extractClass.html).

Martin Fowler, one of the premier software craftsman in the industry wrote a fantastic book on the concepts of refactoring that you can find [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201485672).  This book will give you step-by-step recipes to tackle a large majority of the refactorings you will ever need.

Also, [JetBrains](http://jetbrains.com) makes some really good IDEs for almost any language that have some really nice refactoring tools built in.  They also have a plugin for Visual Studio called [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) that provides some of the same features and benefits.

Comment: Can't find this in current IDE :-(  What I want is to be able to highlight a range of lines, then select "extract *function*", with *all* inputs as input parameters, and *all* result values as multi-return or a return paramater object (depending on language), rather than data division, er, member field updates/side-effects.  If I want to move some of the input params and/or return values into the "data division", I can later.  (yeah, feelin' the hate for Java as COBOL, and the utter loss of the cultural ability to write pure functions)

Answer (score 0):

The practice is called refactoring.

Refactoring came from the mathematics idea of factors. So effectively you are splitting your method up to get the same result.

Edit I do this from the get-go. I'll write a load of code and look on how I can remove duplication at ver small increments. It is part of the TDD mantra.

red. green. refactor to remove duplication.

Comment: It's not refactoring if you implement a class from the get-go like this, for example. I'm looking for a paradigm, not a practice.

Answer (score 0):

The breaking up of large functions into smaller ones is usually called Refactoring, but the act of combining smaller functions together is called [Composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition_%28computer_science%29).

Composition is particularly powerful when your programming language supports functions as first-class entities, meaning you can pass a function as an argument to another function, which returns a new function that didn't exist until runtime.